# I get message of open json file everytime while compiling code on VS code. How do I settle this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to debug I encounter this error

I tried to delete the file but couldn't get rid of it

Comment: Sounds like its the launch.json file.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: read the VSC doc pages about debugging